# After installing a package from ec2, the connection is suddenly disconnected

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

After installing a package from ec2(g4ad), the connection is suddenly disconnected.

in ec2 i clone github and install setting.sh

```
AWS_KEY="ys-oregon2.pem"
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i $AWS_KEY ubuntu@$INSTANCE_DNS 'git clone https://github.com/anonymous-ppp/ppp.git'
ssh -i $AWS_KEY -t ubuntu@$INSTANCE_DNS 'cd /home/ubuntu/ppp/data_generation/;sudo bash ./settings.sh'
```

After running this, the connection suddenly drops.

> Successfully installed absl-py-0.15.0 astunparse-1.6.3 cachetools-4.2.4 gast-0.3.3 google-auth-1.23.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.1 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.41.1 gviz-api-1.10.0 h5py-2.10.0 importlib-metadata-2.1.2 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 markdown-3.2.2 numpy-1.18.5 oauthlib-3.1.0 opt-einsum-3.3.0 protobuf-3.19.1 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 requests-2.25.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 scipy-1.4.1 setuptools-50.3.2 six-1.16.0 tensorboard-2.3.0 tensorboard-plugin-profile-2.3.0 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.1 tensorflow-2.3.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-1.0.1 wrapt-1.13.3 zipp-1.2.0

> Connection to ec2-54-149-187-13.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed.

Comment: ec2 instance also terminated? if yes, then you can find details in the instance history tab on ec2. sometimes the connection is also lost if the instance is restarted by Amazon EC2.

Comment: You can also check system logs by going to "Actions"->instance settings-> get system logs.